# Find out which PIP modules are really in use

Tags: python, django, debugging, pip, virtualenv

I am still in my dev environment (in a virtual environment), So I have installed some pip packages to test or trying ways to do something. Now I am wondering if it is possible to find out which of those modules are really in use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic way to see what packages are actually in use.  The easiest option would be:

1. Create and activate a new, empty virtualenv.
2. Try to run your code. When it fails because of a missing dependency, `pip install` the missing package.
3. Repeat step 2 until everything works.
4. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to record the final requirements.